# How to execute C++ linux program using PHP/Laravel on Apache server?

Tags: php, linux

I want to run a C++ program (compiled on linux) with PHP/Laravel on a linux Apache server.

PHP command Exec(), Shell_exec(), Passthru(), System() does'nt work on the server.

I test with a script.sh, does'nt work on the server but work on my local linux.

The executable was in "public/exe/myfolder" folder and I use "/exe/myfolder/myprogram" to access program.

The code to run script :

```
$cmd = shell_exec('./exe/eleccurve/scriptub.sh');
```

The code to run the program :

```
$cmd = system('./exe/eleccurve/ElecCurveMotor');
```

System() return "" and not run the program.

Or :

```
$cmd = shell_exec('./exe/eleccurve/ElecCurveMotor');
```

Shell_exec() return "null" and not run the program.

Or :

```
$cmd = exec('./exe/eleccurve/ElecCurveMotor', $out, $res);
```

exec() return "", $out = [], $res = 0 and not run the program.

Or :

```
$cmd = passthru('./exe/eleccurve/ElecCurveMotor', $out);
```

passthru() return "null", $out = 0 and not run the program.

The script.sh (int the same folder) :

```
#! /bin/sh
./ElecCurveMotor
```

Anyone had an idea and have I missed anything ?

Comment: you need to check that your PHP group can run the script

Comment: I give the access rights with this commands : sudo chgrp -R www-data DICOGEN
sudo chown -R root DICOGEN
sudo chmod -R 775 DICOGEN

Comment: WHen i run the script with prompt command, it's work, but not byt the web interface

Comment: Anyone have an idea ?